# Очистить поле input после отправки сообщения

Tags: input

После отправки сообщения, написанный текст в поле input не стирается.
Тем самым если нажимать Enter будет отправляться одно и тоже, пока вручную не стереть текст в поле.
Нужно, чтобы после отправки сообщения, текст написанный в поле input автоматически очищался.

```html
<input type="hidden" name="custom1" class="mchat" id="mchatC1F" value="/images/noavatar.gif" />
<input type="hidden" name="custom2" value="active" />
<div align="left"><input type="text" name="mcmessage" class="mchat" id="mchatMsgF" maxlength="500" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Написать..." /></div>

<input type="submit" onclick="messages();setTimeout(function(){messages()},500)" value="Отправить" class="mchat2" id="mchatBtn" />
<input type="hidden" name="email" value="1@yraaa.ru">
<input style="visibility:hidden" id="mchatAjax" type="button" value="Отправить" class="mchat2" disabled />
```

Comment: messages();setTimeout(function(){messages()},500) - зачем это два раза повторяется?

Comment: вроде бы один раз же, я просто сам не особо разбираюсь в этом

Comment: При клике отправить вы 2 раза вызываете message(). Я пытаюсь понять зачем?

Answer (score 2):

```
var mchatField = document.getElementById('mchatMsgF');

function messages() {
    //Ваша функция и в конце добавить
    mchatField.value = '';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
onclick ="var self = this; setTimeout(function(){self.value=''}, 500)"
```

Такое решение в лоб. Годится только для верстки, в продакшене быть не должно